# Exportar funciones con module exports discordjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Hola como puedo exportar esta funcion con module exports, formule recientemente una pregunta con la misma situacion pero hice unos cambios en el codigo para que sea mas sencillla su compresion teniendo el mismo objetivo, el error que me tira es que message no esta definido, como lo soluciono?

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


function uno_a_tres() {

  message.channel.send(message.author.username)

}

module.exports = {uno_a_tres}
```

Comment: La forma en que lo haces es correcta y el error también. ¿donde tienes la variable `message`? Yo no la veo

Comment: es que no se como declarala, fijate que estoy usando message.channel.send ahi uso message y no lo toma, como lo declaro?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `discordjs` estás usando?

Comment: La version es la 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final era algo tan tonto como declarar en mi archivo de funcion algo asi:

```
module.exports = async function listo(message) {}
```

no es necesario declarar la funcion listo se podria hacer tambien con => (message) {//y aca el codigo} pero yo lo deje asi porque funciono y listo (por eso le puse de nombre listo) y le puse el async porque tenia que ejecutar un await pero no es necesario ojo tambien es necesario declarar en el archivo en el cual se llame a la funcion la variable requerida ejemplo:

```
const x = require('la direccion del archivo de funcion);

x(message)
```

espero les sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la forma que lo estas haciendo, pero necesitas dos cosas: `message` no esta definido en esa función, así que tendrás que pasarlo como parámetro cuando la quieras llamar.

Para poder usar la función necesitaras guardarla desde donde la quieras llamar:

```
const {uno_a_tres} = require("direccion/de/tu/funcion")
```

Comment: Hola gracias, pareció funcionar pero me tira que no sabe que devolver, llame a la función como vos me dijiste y tenía fe porque parecía un buena solución pero no me supo que devolver cuando trate de usar la función en el comando, en el comando puse message.channel.send(uno_a_tres()) lo puse así porque sin paréntesis tiraba también error y me pareció más lógico poner paréntesis. Alguna ayudita?

Comment: @Desa_QDila has probado exportando sin un objeto? `module.exports = uno_a_tres`

Comment: si probe pero se pone todo en amarillo y no me reconoce es basicanete lo mismo